# Amazon Lex: can't make mobile app work

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-mobilehub, amazon-lex

I have a bot that works perfectly in the AWS console.

I've tried to make it work in a mobile app using AWS MobileHub but it doesn't work well and I don't know why I'm totally stuck.

Description: I make a request with a project name to get the list of tasks on this project. But first I have to connect. The "connection" request gets a token from my backend and put it in *sessionAttributes*. The other requests must have this token in *sessionAttributes* or the bot will ask to authenticate.

The workflow works with the AWS console bot:

1. Request *"tasks for project 123"* -> Answer *"you must authenticate"*
2. Request *"connection"* -> Answer *"you are now connected"*
3. Request *"tasks for project 123"* -> Answer *"tasks for project 123
   are 4, 8, 11. Choose a task to get details."*

---

Now what happens with the app, in text mode:

1. Request *"tasks for project 123"* -> Answer *"you must authenticate"*
2. Request *"connection"* -> No answer
3. Request *"tasks for project 123"* -> The app crashes

Logs in Android Studio at step 3 (crash):

```
06-28 11:05:58.942 1719-1719/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.amazon.mysampleapp, PID: 1719
Theme: themes:{default=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, iconPack:com.cyngn.hexo, fontPkg:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo, com.android.systemui.navbar=overlay:com.cyngn.hexo}
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.continuations.LexServiceContinuation.continueWithTextInForTextOut(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
at com.mysampleapp.demo.bots.ConversationalBotTextFragment.textEntered(ConversationalBotTextFragment.java:135)
at com.mysampleapp.demo.bots.ConversationalBotTextFragment.access$000(ConversationalBotTextFragment.java:42)
at com.mysampleapp.demo.bots.ConversationalBotTextFragment$1.onKey(ConversationalBotTextFragment.java:86)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:9236)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1640)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2651)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1777)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2731)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:543)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:312)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2363)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4135)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4097)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3703)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3795)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3677)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3852)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3703)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3669)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3677)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3650)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5932)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5906)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5867)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3442)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-28 11:05:58.944 789-3750/? W/ActivityManager: Force finishing activity com.amazon.mysampleapp/com.mysampleapp.MainActivity
```

---

And here with the voice on mobile app:

1. Request *"tasks for project 123"* -> Answer *"you must authenticate"*
2. Request *"connection"* -> Answer *"you are now connected"*
3. Request *"tasks for project 123"* -> Answer *"you must authenticate"*

Logs in Android Studio at steps 1 and 3:

```
06-28 11:24:15.227 4265-4265/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/Lex: InteractiveVoiceViewAdapter: Interaction error
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.exceptions.DialogFailedException: Failed to fulfill current request.
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.InteractionClient$8.run(InteractionClient.java:593)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
06-28 11:24:15.227 4265-4265/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/ConversationalBotVoice: Error: You must authenticate.
com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.exceptions.DialogFailedException: Failed to fulfill current request.
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.InteractionClient$8.run(InteractionClient.java:593)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5461)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

---

So I tried to change the lambda so I don't need the connection part (but still it uses the token for the requests, I've just written the token in the lambda instead of getting it from the backend).

- In AWS console, I get the tasks list
- On mobile with text, I get the tasks list
- On mobile with voice, it doesn't work

And the logs for that last case:

```
06-28 11:38:40.619 7655-7655/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/Lex: InteractiveVoiceViewAdapter: Interaction error
com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.model.DependencyFailedException: Received error response from Lambda: Handled (Service: AmazonLexRuntime; Status Code: 424; Error Code: DependencyFailedException; Request ID: 8f30ae21-5be5-11e7-bc7b-8d61d03f20da)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:729)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.invoke(AmazonLexRuntimeClient.java:651)
at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.postContent(AmazonLexRuntimeClient.java:450)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.InteractionClient$2.run(InteractionClient.java:375)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-28 11:38:40.620 7655-7655/com.amazon.mysampleapp E/ConversationalBotVoice: Error: Error from Bot
com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.model.DependencyFailedException: Received error response from Lambda: Handled (Service: AmazonLexRuntime; Status Code: 424; Error Code: DependencyFailedException; Request ID: 8f30ae21-5be5-11e7-bc7b-8d61d03f20da)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:729)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:405)
at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:212)
at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.invoke(AmazonLexRuntimeClient.java:651)
at com.amazonaws.services.lexrts.AmazonLexRuntimeClient.postContent(AmazonLexRuntimeClient.java:450)
at com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.lex.interactionkit.InteractionClient$2.run(InteractionClient.java:375)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't know what to do, I don't even know how to log things, how to check what is sent to Lex from the app and what Lex sends back. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide some of your code as to how you are doing the AWS calls in each case?

Comment: Looks like your question was answered on the AWS forums: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820922/amazon-lex-cant-make-mobile-app-work (posting in case someone stumbles onto this question)